# IN clause not working on mysql 8.0.17

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0, where, debugging

I was on mysql:8.0.15 and I updated to mysql:8.0.17

- On 8.0.15 `... and (col1, col2) in (('a', 'b'))` the query return results, this is what I expect
- On 8.0.17 the same query with same data return 0 results.

I thought it was our application, so I downgraded back to 8.0.15 and the query is working again...

I noticed `... and (col1, col2) in (('a', 'b'),('a', 'b'))` is working in `8.0.17`

I tried to search mysql bug list, but I can't find any information... In the changelog I see they optimized WHERE IN in 8.0.17, but it should not break my use case.

> The optimizer now transforms a WHERE condition having NOT IN (subquery), NOT EXISTS (subquery), IN (subquery) IS NOT TRUE, or EXISTS (subquery) IS NOT TRUE internally into an antijoin, thus removing the subquery. This is similar to the existing IS NULL (Not exists) outer join optimization; see EXPLAIN Extra Information, for further information.
>   In addition, the semijoin materialization can now be used for a WHERE condition having IN (subquery) IS TRUE, or EXISTS (subquery) IS TRUE, or when the IN condition belongs to a left join such as SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.x IN (SELECT * FROM t3). See Optimizing IN and EXISTS Subquery predicates with Semijoin Transformations.
>   Also as a result of this work, MySQL is now able to simplify a co

It seems too big to be a bug in mysql. Am I missing something ?

Here is the full query

```sql
select `t1`.`user_id`    as `user_id`,
       `t1`.`created_at` as `created_at`,
       `t1`.`updated_at` as `updated_at`,
       `t3`.`node_id`    as `t3node_id`,
       `t3`.`node_type`  as `t3node_type`,
       `t2`.`node_id`    as `t2node_id`,
       `t2`.`node_type`  as `t2node_type`
from `table1` as `t1`
         inner join `table2` as `t2` on `t1`.`set_id` = `t2`.`set_id` and `t1`.`set_type` = `t2`.`set_type`
         left join `table2` as `t3`
                   on `t2`.`node_type` = 3 and `t3`.`set_type` = 5 and `t3`.`set_id` = `t2`.`node_id`
         left join `table3` as `ts` on COALESCE(t3.node_type, t2.node_type) = `ts`.`cache_node_type` and
                                                 COALESCE(t3.node_id, t2.node_id) = `ts`.`cache_node_id`
where `t1`.`tenant_id` = '825773475713154048'
and (`t1`.`user_id`, `t2`.`node_id`) in ( ('825773502556700160', '825773839074099712'))
```

On 8.0.17 I get 0 results. On 8.0.15 it works.

- If, on 8.0.17, I replace the last line by `and (t1.user_id, t2.node_id) in ( ('825773502556700160', '825773839074099712'), ('825773502556700160', '825773839074099712'))` (notice it's the same tuple, two times) I get results.
- It works with this `and (t1.user_id, t2.node_id) = ('825773502556700160', '825773839074099712')`
- I tried with a simple query `SELECT * FROM test.test as t1 WHERE (t1.col1,t1.col2) IN (('a','b'));` it works on 8.0.17.

Comment: The quote talks about "subquery"; your abbreviated code does not have such.  Which case are you talking about?  The are _probably_ optimized very differently.

Comment: As for filing a bug -- do it.  "Row constructors" are only rarely used, and it sounds like some new optimizations are being added.

Comment: Meanwhile, let's see the whole query to discuss workarounds.

Comment: @RickJames I added more infos, thank you

Comment: What data type are the columns `user_id` and `node_id`?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the evil, implicit data type conversion: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f758a590d15037a621b1d60533e6acb

Comment: "*It seems too big to be a bug in mysql*" - well, MySQL was never known for [making quality](http://monty-says.blogspot.de/2008/11/oops-we-did-it-again-mysql-51-released.html) the highest priority.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name They are BIGINT.... I just noticed they are passed as string (thanks to nodejs driver....). It's very strange it is working on 8.0.15.

Comment: Then why are you comparing them as strings? You should pass numbers

Comment: Because in64 isn't supported in nodejs, so the ORM use strings... It was working until now. But the behavior of mysql is still strange, I tried your fiddle and it's not working only if there is 1 tuple in the list. If I add another it's working....

Comment: @user3803241 - Do you _need_ 64-bit numbers?  Almost always 32 is adequate.  Are those somehow fabricated?

Comment: MySQL is happy doing `bigint_column = "123453123123123"` -- That is, numeric column tested against string.  What is troublesome (for performance) is `varchar_column = 123123`, namely `VARCHAR` compared to integer literal.

Comment: @RickJames Yes they are snowflakes ids. I store them as BIGINT. I'll stay on 8.0.15 until I find a way to pass them as number but I'm not sure I can do that easily...

Comment: @user3803241 - That is, 64-bit numbers used by Twitter?  Do they need to be stored in `BIGINT UNSIGNED`, not `BIGINT SIGNED`?  Was Java upgraded at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I store them as UNSIGNED and I don't use Java

Comment: I'll just wait for a working mysql version I think... I'm not sure there is an easy way to convert the string as BIGINT with my driver

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple IN clause other than the one in your code?  If not, I would write a couple simple ones and try them to see if they run.  If they run successfully, it's either you copied it incorrectly, OR it's got to be something specific with how your code is using the IN statement.

If no IN statements run, something was changed, either by design or it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

(too messy for Comment)

If you change

```
and (`t1`.`user_id`, `t2`.`node_id`) in ( ('825773502556700160', '825773839074099712'))
```

to

```
and (`t1`.`user_id` = 825773502556700160
 AND `t2`.`node_id` = 825773839074099712)
```

does 8.0.17 work?

*Note the difference:  You are touching two different tables.  Was that intentional?*

Comment: yes it works but I rarely have only one tuple, most of the time I have more...